# TestNG :- not able to get context.getCurrentXmlTest()

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, testng

I have some other test context with custom logic to import and read 
 "testConfigFile"

But < I'm planing to iterate over multiple tests so, trying to read test data as

```
@DataProvider(name = "testdata")
    public Object[][] testdata(ITestContext context) {
        Map<String, String> parameters = context.getCurrentXmlTest()
                .getAllParameters();
        System.out.println("-------");

        Iterator it = parameters.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();

            String x = (String) pairs.getValue();

            if (x.startsWith("created_")
                    && !pairs.getKey().toString().contains("shareData")) {
                String y = (String) universalMap.get(x);
                parameters.put((String) pairs.getKey(), y);
            }
        }
        return new Object[][] { { parameters } };
    }
```

In which it is not able to detect **context** have a **getCurrentXmlTest()** method even after type casting it as

```
Map<String, String> parameters = (((ITestContext)context).getCurrentXmlTest())
                .getAllParameters();
```

Still it throws :-

```
The method getCurrentXmlTest() is undefined for the type ITestContext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I was using very old testng-5.4-jdk15.jar TestNG library.

Now, I have upgraded it and working fine now.

Thanks.